# Bipartite Graphs and Trees Questions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science, trees

**Which of the claims below is not equivalent to the rest?**

1) Every cycle in a graph "B" has an even length

2) Graph "B" is bipartite

3) Graph "B" has two components that are connected.

4) Graph "B" is two-colorable.

**Which of the claims below is not equivalent to the rest?**

1) Graph "B" is connected and contains no cycles

2) Graph "B" is a tree

3) The maximum degree of "B" is 2.

4) In Graph "B" there is a unique simple path between any 2-vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part (a) Konig's Theorem states that a graph is bipartite if and only if all any cycles present are of even length.

Note that bipartite graphs need not be connected. Consider a graph $G(V, E)$ with $E = \emptyset$. Bipartite and two-colorability are equivalent. I've edited to fix my mistake.

For part (b), consider a star. Is that a tree? The rest of those follow from the definition of a tree.

Comment: Are you suggesting all statements in $(b)$ are equivalent?

Comment: No. Do you know what a star is? The maximum degree of a star is greater than $2$. Looking at a visual, is it a tree? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_%28graph_theory%29

Comment: Excellent. My bad..

Comment: So wait which answer for part A would be false then? Is it #3?

Comment: Three is correct. Now what about (4)? Is $K_{n, n}$ bipartite? Is it two-colorable?

Comment: 4 would be correct as well because part of the definition of a bi-partite graph states: "A graph is bipartite if and only if it is 2-colorable."

Comment: That's correct. My mistake. I've edited my original post to correct my mistake. Sorry for any confusion!

Comment: So wait which one is false? Lol they all look true to me. The only one that looks as if it could be false is #3?

Comment: That is correct. You can have a bipartite graph with no connections. A forest is a great example.